# Network manager and sutdown not working

Tags: networking, dvd, drive

Most of the functionality have stopped working after I changed the permission of `lib` folder. Network manager, shutdown/restart, DVD drive everything stopped working.

Can some one lead me to the right path from disaster?

Comment: What if you try reverting back the changes? Did you try doing a `sudo chown root:root /lib` and `sudo chmod 751 /lib`?

Comment: @Jobin, sudo also not working so i cant change the permission of lib

Comment: Can you try using the "Recovery mode"?

Comment: "Recovery mode" ? can you explain it bit more?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it would be better chowning and chmodding (sorry for those two new word!) recursively? (`chown -R root:root /lib` ...)

@Jobin: why 751? /lib files and subdirectories aren't in 755?

Cheers,

Silvia

Comment: before i did the change , i was logging as the administartor but now it takes me as guest. i could not even  view  the folders created under my home. My admin and sudo privileges gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your machine and press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until the grub appears(the list of options to choose which OS to boot).

When you see the grub, go to "Ubuntu, with linux 3.8.0 (recovery mode)"(you may have a different linux version) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then wait for a menu to appear and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then go to `root`(the second last option) and then type the following in the command prompt that appears on the bottom of the screen(note the spaces in the commands, type them **as they are**):

```
mount -o remount,rw /
chmod 755 /lib
reboot
```

Wait for the machine to reboot and then see if the permissions have changed by logging into your usual account.

Comment: after doing this, permission of the lib got changed but still the problem persisits.I missed to state that i had chnaged the usr folder permission also.Now i reverted /usr folder permission to read only.

Comment: Why did you revert the permission to `/usr` as read-only and not as its default(755)?

Comment: Yeah 755 only i used to change.i just wrote that i saw in terminal while using 755 to change permision..